# Finding Lighting Direction from lunar image using crater shadow

Tags: computer-vision

I am very new to computer vision and image processing and working on a problem of detecting light direction (sun azimuth and elevation) using only a single image. I attempted the method mentioned in "Determining Light Direction in Spheres using Average Gradient by Richard Dosselmann". But I couldn't get the azimuth or elevation angles properly. I tried to calculate image gradients (gx and gy) using sobel operator and taken average of gx and gy. Using arctan(gy,gx), I was trying to get an elevation angle. but it didn't work properly. To elaborate my problem, from the following lunar crater image, the solar azimuth with respect to north is 90degree and elevation is 45degree, what I suppose to find.[lunar crater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr0cj.png). Please help me in finding lighting source direction by using only an image.

Comment: if you are wondering why you don't get an answer, please note that you did not ask a question. please read [ask]

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. My objective is to find lighting source direction by using only an image.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question. I would try the following approach:

1. Detect circles in the image using Hough transform. You will have to adjust the thresholds so that both the crater and its shadow are detected.
2. For each pair of overlapping circles, get the pair of centers.
3. Use the pair to calculate lighting direction. I am not sure if you can calculate both the azimuth and the elevation with only one pair, but with multiple pairs you should be able to come up with a least squares-like method.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me an clue. Please let me know if any success from your side.

Comment: "I would try" is a way of recommending an approach; I guess I won't be able to actually write any code to try this until the weekend.